# ERROR "Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 1: 6874 >= 6874" while writing encoded output to an mp4 file

Tags: c, ffmpeg, tcp, rtsp, aac

I have a running RTSP stream, streaming video on a loop using the following FFMPEG command:

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i ./ffmpeg_c_test/small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4 -ac 2 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream
```

The video file is obtained from the github link: https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial

I keep getting error response, when I calling the function `av_interleaved_write_frame` called from the function `remux` in the attached program. The output format is `mp4`, output video codec is `av1` and output audio codec is same as input audio codec. The error is from audio stream.

I tried to create a "minimal reproducible code", however, I think it is still not completely minimal, but it reproduces the exact error.

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct StreamingContext{
    AVFormatContext* avfc;
    const AVCodec *video_avc;
    const AVCodec *audio_avc;
    AVStream *video_avs;
    AVStream *audio_avs;
    AVCodecContext *video_avcc;
    AVCodecContext *audio_avcc;
    int video_index;
    int audio_index;
    char* filename;
    struct SwsContext *sws_ctx;
}StreamingContext;


typedef struct StreamingParams{
    char copy_video;
    char copy_audio;
    char *output_extension;
    char *muxer_opt_key;
    char *muxer_opt_value;
    char *video_codec;
    char *audio_codec;
    char *codec_priv_key;
    char *codec_priv_value;
}StreamingParams;

void logging(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    fprintf(stderr, "LOG: ");
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}

int fill_stream_info(AVStream *avs, const AVCodec **avc, AVCodecContext **avcc)
{
    *avc = avcodec_find_decoder(avs->codecpar->codec_id);
    *avcc = avcodec_alloc_context3(*avc);
    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(*avcc, avs->codecpar) < 0)
    {
        logging("Failed to fill Codec Context.");
        return -1;
    }
    avcodec_open2(*avcc, *avc, NULL);
    return 0;
}

int open_media(const char *in_filename, AVFormatContext **avfc)
{
    *avfc = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (avformat_open_input(avfc, in_filename, NULL, NULL) != 0)
    {
        logging("Failed to open input file %s", in_filename);
        return -1;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(*avfc, NULL) < 0)
    {
        logging("Failed to get Stream Info.");
        return -1;
    }
}

int prepare_decoder(StreamingContext *sc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)sc->avfc->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if (sc->avfc->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            sc->video_avs = sc->avfc->streams[i];
            sc->video_index = i;

            if (fill_stream_info(sc->video_avs, &sc->video_avc, &sc->video_avcc))
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else if (sc->avfc->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            sc->audio_avs = sc->avfc->streams[i];
            sc->audio_index = i;

            if (fill_stream_info(sc->audio_avs, &sc->audio_avc, &sc->audio_avcc))
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logging("Skipping Streams other than Audio and Video.");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int prepare_video_encoder(StreamingContext *encoder_sc, AVCodecContext *decoder_ctx, AVRational input_framerate,
                          StreamingParams sp, int scaled_frame_width, int scaled_frame_height)
{
    encoder_sc->video_avs = avformat_new_stream(encoder_sc->avfc, NULL);
    encoder_sc->video_avc = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(sp.video_codec);
    if (!encoder_sc->video_avc)
    {
        logging("Cannot find the Codec.");
        return -1;
    }

    encoder_sc->video_avcc = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder_sc->video_avc);
    if (!encoder_sc->video_avcc)
    {
        logging("Could not allocate memory for Codec Context.");
        return -1;
    }

    av_opt_set(encoder_sc->video_avcc->priv_data, "preset", "fast", 0);
    if (sp.codec_priv_key && sp.codec_priv_value)
        av_opt_set(encoder_sc->video_avcc->priv_data, sp.codec_priv_key, sp.codec_priv_value, 0);

    encoder_sc->video_avcc->height = scaled_frame_height;
    encoder_sc->video_avcc->width = scaled_frame_width;
    encoder_sc->video_avcc->sample_aspect_ratio = decoder_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio;

    if (encoder_sc->video_avc->pix_fmts)
        encoder_sc->video_avcc->pix_fmt = encoder_sc->video_avc->pix_fmts[0];
    else
        encoder_sc->video_avcc->pix_fmt = decoder_ctx->pix_fmt;

    encoder_sc->video_avcc->bit_rate = 2 * 1000 * 1000;

    encoder_sc->video_avcc->time_base = av_inv_q(input_framerate);
    encoder_sc->video_avs->time_base = encoder_sc->video_avcc->time_base;

    

    if (avcodec_open2(encoder_sc->video_avcc, encoder_sc->video_avc, NULL) < 0)
    {
        logging("Could not open the Codec.");
        return -1;
    }
    avcodec_parameters_from_context(encoder_sc->video_avs->codecpar, encoder_sc->video_avcc);
    return 0;
}


int prepare_copy(AVFormatContext *avfc, AVStream **avs, AVCodecParameters *decoder_par)
{
    *avs = avformat_new_stream(avfc, NULL);
    avcodec_parameters_copy((*avs)->codecpar, decoder_par);
    return 0;
}

int encode_video(StreamingContext *decoder, StreamingContext *encoder, AVFrame *input_frame)
{
    if (input_frame)
        input_frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_NONE;

    AVPacket *output_packet = av_packet_alloc();


    int response = avcodec_send_frame(encoder->video_avcc, input_frame);

    while (response >= 0)
    {
        response = avcodec_receive_packet(encoder->video_avcc, output_packet);
        if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            break;
        }

        output_packet->stream_index = decoder->video_index;
        output_packet->duration = encoder->video_avs->time_base.den / encoder->video_avs->time_base.num;

        av_packet_rescale_ts(output_packet, decoder->video_avs->time_base, encoder->video_avs->time_base);
        response = av_interleaved_write_frame(encoder->avfc, output_packet);
    }

    av_packet_unref(output_packet);
    av_packet_free(&output_packet);

    return 0;
}

int remux(AVPacket **pkt, AVFormatContext **avfc, AVRational decoder_tb, AVRational encoder_tb)
{
    (*pkt)->duration = av_rescale_q((*pkt)->duration, decoder_tb, encoder_tb);
    (*pkt)->pos = -1;
    av_packet_rescale_ts(*pkt, decoder_tb, encoder_tb);
    if (av_interleaved_write_frame(*avfc, *pkt) < 0)
    {
        logging("Error while copying Stream Packet.");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int transcode_video(StreamingContext *decoder, StreamingContext *encoder, AVPacket *input_packet, AVFrame *input_frame)
{
    int response = avcodec_send_packet(decoder->video_avcc, input_packet);
    while (response >= 0)
    {
        response = avcodec_receive_frame(decoder->video_avcc, input_frame);
        
        if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (response >= 0)
        {
            if (encode_video(decoder, encoder, input_frame))
                return -1;
        }

        av_frame_unref(input_frame);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int scaled_frame_width = 854;
    const int scaled_frame_height = 480;
    StreamingParams sp = {0};
    sp.copy_audio = 1;
    sp.copy_video = 0;
    sp.video_codec = "libsvtav1";
    
    StreamingContext *decoder = (StreamingContext *)calloc(1, sizeof(StreamingContext));
    decoder->filename = "rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream";

    StreamingContext *encoder = (StreamingContext *)calloc(1, sizeof(StreamingContext));
    encoder->filename = "small_bunny_9.mp4";
    
    if (sp.output_extension)
    {
        strcat(encoder->filename, sp.output_extension);
    }

    open_media(decoder->filename, &decoder->avfc);
    prepare_decoder(decoder);


    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&encoder->avfc, NULL, "mp4", encoder->filename);
    AVRational input_framerate = av_guess_frame_rate(decoder->avfc, decoder->video_avs, NULL);
    prepare_video_encoder(encoder, decoder->video_avcc, input_framerate, sp, scaled_frame_width, scaled_frame_height);

    prepare_copy(encoder->avfc, &encoder->audio_avs, decoder->audio_avs->codecpar);
        

    if (encoder->avfc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        encoder->avfc->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    if (!(encoder->avfc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        if (avio_open(&encoder->avfc->pb, encoder->filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0)
        {
            logging("could not open the output file");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    
    if (avformat_write_header(encoder->avfc, NULL) < 0)
    {
        logging("an error occurred when opening output file");
        return -1;
    }

    AVFrame *input_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    AVPacket *input_packet = av_packet_alloc();

    while (1)
    {
        int ret = av_read_frame(decoder->avfc, input_packet);
        if(ret<0)
            break;
        if (decoder->avfc->streams[input_packet->stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            if (transcode_video(decoder, encoder, input_packet, input_frame))
                return -1;
            av_packet_unref(input_packet);

        }
        else if (decoder->avfc->streams[input_packet->stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            
                if (remux(&input_packet, &encoder->avfc, decoder->audio_avs->time_base, encoder->audio_avs->time_base))
                    return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            logging("Ignoring all nonvideo or audio packets.");
        }
    }

    if (encode_video(decoder, encoder, NULL))
        return -1;
    

    av_write_trailer(encoder->avfc);


    if (input_frame != NULL)
    {
        av_frame_free(&input_frame);
        input_frame = NULL;
    }

    if (input_packet != NULL)
    {
        av_packet_free(&input_packet);
        input_packet = NULL;
    }

    avformat_close_input(&decoder->avfc);

    avformat_free_context(decoder->avfc);
    decoder->avfc = NULL;
    avformat_free_context(encoder->avfc);
    encoder->avfc = NULL;

    avcodec_free_context(&decoder->video_avcc);
    decoder->video_avcc = NULL;
    avcodec_free_context(&decoder->audio_avcc);
    decoder->audio_avcc = NULL;

    free(decoder);
    decoder = NULL;
    free(encoder);
    encoder = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may correct the DTS timestamps when remuxing the audio packets for making sure that the DTS timestamps are monotonously increased.

The "non monotonically increasing dts" issue is mainly a result of streaming the input video file in a **loop**.

Each time the loop starts, the timestamps starts from the beginning.
The remuxing procedure copies the timestamps from the input to the output, so there is a "non-increased DTS scenario" each time the loop restarts.

We have to fix the DTS timestamps to keep them monotonously increased.
We may also fix the PTS timestamps the same way, because the PTS should match the DTS in a valid audio stream.

---

Note:
For keeping the synchronization between the audio and the video, we may also have to fix the timesteps of video stream.

After fixing the audio, the video encoding is also not working.
My answer is going to address only the "non monotonically increasing dts" issue.
Fixing the video stream seems too challenging.

Note:
Using AV1 video encoder may raise other issues, since AV1 encoding may not meet the Realtime constraints (can't keep up with the rate of streaming input).
For getting a playable output file, I used `libx264` encoder instead of `libsvtav1`.
In case your CPU is "strong" enough, AV1 may also work.

---

For "manually" fixing the DTS (and PTS) timestamps, we may use the following structure for tracking the timestamps and the required offsets:

```
typedef struct TimestampsTracking{
    int64_t prv_pts;
    int64_t pts_offset;
    int64_t prv_dts;
    int64_t dts_offset;
    int64_t prv_duration;
} TimestampsTracking;
```

Pass a pointer to the structure to `remux` function:

```
int remux(AVPacket **pkt, AVFormatContext **avfc, AVRational decoder_tb, AVRational encoder_tb, TimestampsTracking *tt)
```

After `av_packet_rescale_ts(*pkt, decoder_tb, encoder_tb)`, keep the original timestamps, and add offsets that fixes the timestamps:

```
int64_t orig_pts = (*pkt)->pts;
int64_t orig_dts = (*pkt)->dts;
(*pkt)->pts += tt->pts_offset; //Add offset to PTS (the offset ensures that the PTS are correct after each loop of the input video file).
(*pkt)->dts += tt->dts_offset; //Add offset to DTS (the offset ensures that the DTS are correct and monotonous after each loop of the input video file).
```

After adding the offset, we may check if the timestamps are not monotonically increased.
In case they are not monotonically increased, fix the timestamp to be monotonically increased, and update the offset (to be used in the next packet):

```
if ((*pkt)->dts < tt->prv_dts)
{
    //Wrapped around...
    //Set the DTS to be the previous DTS plus duration of a single packet.
    //Note: add the duration of the previous packet instead of adding (*pkt)->duration, because the last audio packet in the file may be shorter than the nominal audio packet duration.
    (*pkt)->dts = tt->prv_dts + tt->prv_duration;
    tt->dts_offset = (*pkt)->dts - orig_dts;
}

//Use the same solution for the PTS...
```

We also have to store the timestamps for to be used in the next packet:

```
tt->prv_pts = (*pkt)->pts;  //Store PTS of previous packet
tt->prv_dts = (*pkt)->dts;  //Store DTS of previous packet
tt->prv_duration = (*pkt)->duration; //Store the duration of the previous packet.
```

Now we can execute `av_interleaved_write_frame` without getting an error:

```
if (av_interleaved_write_frame(*avfc, *pkt) < 0)
{
    logging("Error while copying Stream Packet.");
    return -1;
}
```

---

Complete updated code:

- See the updated code at the bottom.
  (I can't post both samples due to characters limit).

---

Note:

- I apologize I couldn't fix the output video stream - it's just too challenging...

---

### Update:

The source of the problem is related to the timestamps of the input audio and video due to the looping.
We may correct the timestamps of the input using `setpts` and `asetpts` filters:

`ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v];[0:a]asetpts=N/SR/TB[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream`

We may still need a DTS timestamps protection at the beginning (but we may simplify the logic).

---

For getting valid output file, we have to close the output file gracefully.

Instead of `while(1)`, we may loop until `Esc` key is pressed.

In Windows, we may use `_kbhit()` and `_getch()` functions for getting the last key pressed without blocking.

Updated code sample:

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

//Include conio.h for using _kbhit (Windows only).
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct StreamingContext{
    AVFormatContext* avfc;
    const AVCodec *video_avc;
    const AVCodec *audio_avc;
    AVStream *video_avs;
    AVStream *audio_avs;
    AVCodecContext *video_avcc;
    AVCodecContext *audio_avcc;
    int video_index;
    int audio_index;
    char* filename;
    struct SwsContext *sws_ctx;
}StreamingContext;


typedef struct StreamingParams{
    char copy_video;
    char copy_audio;
    char *output_extension;
    char *muxer_opt_key;
    char *muxer_opt_value;
    char *video_codec;
    char *audio_codec;
    char *codec_priv_key;
    char *codec_priv_value;
}StreamingParams;



//Track the PTS and DTS timestamps for adjusting the offset
//Adding offset is used for avoiding non-monotonous timestamps. 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
typedef struct TimestampsTracking{
    int64_t prv_pts;
    int64_t pts_offset;
    int64_t prv_dts;
    int64_t dts_offset;
    int64_t prv_duration;
} TimestampsTracking;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


void logging(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    fprintf(stderr, "LOG: ");
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}

int fill_stream_info(AVStream *avs, const AVCodec **avc, AVCodecContext **avcc)
{
    *avc = avcodec_find_decoder(avs->codecpar->codec_id);
    *avcc = avcodec_alloc_context3(*avc);
    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(*avcc, avs->codecpar) < 0)
    {
        logging("Failed to fill Codec Context.");
        return -1;
    }
    avcodec_open2(*avcc, *avc, NULL);
    return 0;
}

int open_media(const char *in_filename, AVFormatContext **avfc)
{
    *avfc = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (avformat_open_input(avfc, in_filename, NULL, NULL) != 0)
    {
        logging("Failed to open input file %s", in_filename);
        return -1;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(*avfc, NULL) < 0)
    {
        logging("Failed to get Stream Info.");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int prepare_decoder(StreamingContext *sc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)sc->avfc->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if (sc->avfc->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            sc->video_avs = sc->avfc->streams[i];
            sc->video_index = i;

            if (fill_stream_info(sc->video_avs, &sc->video_avc, &sc->video_avcc))
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else if (sc->avfc->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            sc->audio_avs = sc->avfc->streams[i];
            sc->audio_index = i;

            if (fill_stream_info(sc->audio_avs, &sc->audio_avc, &sc->audio_avcc))
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logging("Skipping Streams other than Audio and Video.");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int prepare_video_encoder(StreamingContext *encoder_sc, AVCodecContext *decoder_ctx, AVRational input_framerate,
                          StreamingParams sp, int scaled_frame_width, int scaled_frame_height)
{
    encoder_sc->video_avs = avformat_new_stream(encoder_sc->avfc, NULL);
    encoder_sc->video_avc = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(sp.video_codec);
    if (!encoder_sc->video_avc)
    {
        logging("Cannot find the Codec.");
        return -1;
    }

    encoder_sc->video_avcc = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder_sc->video_avc);
    if (!encoder_sc->video_avcc)
    {
        logging("Could not allocate memory for Codec Context.");
        return -1;
    }

    av_opt_set(encoder_sc->video_avcc->priv_data, "preset", "fast", 0);  //Unable to parse option value "fast"
    //av_opt_set(encoder_sc->video_avcc->priv_data, "preset", "-1", 0);  //Encoding preset (from -1 to 13) (default -1)
    if (sp.codec_priv_key && sp.codec_priv_value)
        av_opt_set(encoder_sc->video_avcc->priv_data, sp.codec_priv_key, sp.codec_priv_value, 0);

    encoder_sc->video_avcc->height = scaled_frame_height;
    encoder_sc->video_avcc->width = scaled_frame_width;
    encoder_sc->video_avcc->sample_aspect_ratio = decoder_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio;

    if (encoder_sc->video_avc->pix_fmts)
        encoder_sc->video_avcc->pix_fmt = encoder_sc->video_avc->pix_fmts[0];
    else
        encoder_sc->video_avcc->pix_fmt = decoder_ctx->pix_fmt;

    encoder_sc->video_avcc->bit_rate = 2 * 1000 * 1000;

    encoder_sc->video_avcc->time_base = av_inv_q(input_framerate);
    encoder_sc->video_avs->time_base = encoder_sc->video_avcc->time_base;

    

    if (avcodec_open2(encoder_sc->video_avcc, encoder_sc->video_avc, NULL) < 0)
    {
        logging("Could not open the Codec.");
        return -1;
    }
    avcodec_parameters_from_context(encoder_sc->video_avs->codecpar, encoder_sc->video_avcc);
    return 0;
}


int prepare_copy(AVFormatContext *avfc, AVStream **avs, AVCodecParameters *decoder_par)
{
    *avs = avformat_new_stream(avfc, NULL);
    avcodec_parameters_copy((*avs)->codecpar, decoder_par);
    return 0;
}

int encode_video(StreamingContext *decoder, StreamingContext *encoder, AVFrame *input_frame)
{
    if (input_frame)
        input_frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_NONE;

    AVPacket *output_packet = av_packet_alloc();


    int response = avcodec_send_frame(encoder->video_avcc, input_frame);

    while (response >= 0)
    {
        response = avcodec_receive_packet(encoder->video_avcc, output_packet);
        if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            break;
        }

        output_packet->stream_index = decoder->video_index;
        output_packet->duration = encoder->video_avs->time_base.den / encoder->video_avs->time_base.num;

        av_packet_rescale_ts(output_packet, decoder->video_avs->time_base, encoder->video_avs->time_base);
        response = av_interleaved_write_frame(encoder->avfc, output_packet);
    }

    av_packet_unref(output_packet);
    av_packet_free(&output_packet);

    return 0;
}

//Add TimestampsTracking argument to remux function.
int remux(AVPacket **pkt, AVFormatContext **avfc, AVRational decoder_tb, AVRational encoder_tb, TimestampsTracking *tt)
{
    (*pkt)->duration = av_rescale_q((*pkt)->duration, decoder_tb, encoder_tb);
    (*pkt)->pos = -1;

    av_packet_rescale_ts(*pkt, decoder_tb, encoder_tb);

    int64_t orig_pts = (*pkt)->pts;
    int64_t orig_dts = (*pkt)->dts;
    (*pkt)->pts += tt->pts_offset; //Add offset to PTS (the offset ensures that the PTS are correct after each loop of the input video file).
    (*pkt)->dts += tt->dts_offset; //Add offset to DTS (the offset ensures that the DTS are correct and monotonous after each loop of the input video file).

    //The input video file wrapped around - we have to fix dts_offset for keeping the DTS monotonous increment.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if ((*pkt)->dts <= tt->prv_dts)
    {
        //Wrapped around...
        //Set the DTS to be the previous DTS plus duration of a single packet.
        //Note: add the duration of the previous packet instead of adding (*pkt)->duration, because the last audio packet in the file may be shorter than the nominal audio packet duration.
        (*pkt)->dts = tt->prv_dts + tt->prv_duration;
        tt->dts_offset = (*pkt)->dts - orig_dts;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Use the same solution for the PTS
    //In case of audio, the PTS are monotonously increased.
    //In case of video the PTS may not be monotonously increased (due to B-Frames).
    //The solution may not work for video packets.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if ((*pkt)->pts <= tt->prv_pts)
    {
        //Wrapped around...
        (*pkt)->pts = tt->prv_pts + tt->prv_duration;  //Set the PTS to be the previous PTS plus duration of a single packet.
        tt->pts_offset = (*pkt)->pts - orig_pts;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //printf("dts = %lld\n", (*pkt)->dts);
    //printf("DTS delta = %lld\n", (*pkt)->dts - tt->prv_dts);


    tt->prv_pts = (*pkt)->pts;  //Store PTS of previous packet
    tt->prv_dts = (*pkt)->dts;  //Store DTS of previous packet
    tt->prv_duration = (*pkt)->duration; //Store the duration of the previous packet.


    if (av_interleaved_write_frame(*avfc, *pkt) < 0)
    {
        logging("Error while copying Stream Packet.");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int transcode_video(StreamingContext *decoder, StreamingContext *encoder, AVPacket *input_packet, AVFrame *input_frame)
{
    int response = avcodec_send_packet(decoder->video_avcc, input_packet);
    while (response >= 0)
    {
        response = avcodec_receive_frame(decoder->video_avcc, input_frame);
        
        if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (response >= 0)
        {
            if (encode_video(decoder, encoder, input_frame))
                return -1;
        }

        av_frame_unref(input_frame);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    const int scaled_frame_width = 854;
    const int scaled_frame_height = 480;
    StreamingParams sp = {0};

    //TimestampsTracking is used for avoiding non-monotonous timestamps. 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    TimestampsTracking audio_tt = {0};
    audio_tt.prv_pts = 0;
    audio_tt.pts_offset = 0;
    audio_tt.prv_dts = 0;
    audio_tt.dts_offset = 0;
    audio_tt.prv_duration = 0;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    sp.copy_audio = 1;
    sp.copy_video = 0;
    //sp.video_codec = "libsvtav1";
    sp.video_codec = "libx264";  //Use libx264 codec for testing
    
    StreamingContext *decoder = (StreamingContext *)calloc(1, sizeof(StreamingContext));
    decoder->filename = "rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream";

    StreamingContext *encoder = (StreamingContext *)calloc(1, sizeof(StreamingContext));
    encoder->filename = "small_bunny_9.mp4";
    
    if (sp.output_extension)
    {
        strcat(encoder->filename, sp.output_extension);
    }

    open_media(decoder->filename, &decoder->avfc);
    prepare_decoder(decoder);


    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&encoder->avfc, NULL, "mp4", encoder->filename);
    AVRational input_framerate = av_guess_frame_rate(decoder->avfc, decoder->video_avs, NULL);
    prepare_video_encoder(encoder, decoder->video_avcc, input_framerate, sp, scaled_frame_width, scaled_frame_height);

    prepare_copy(encoder->avfc, &encoder->audio_avs, decoder->audio_avs->codecpar);
        

    if (encoder->avfc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        encoder->avfc->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    if (!(encoder->avfc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        if (avio_open(&encoder->avfc->pb, encoder->filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0)
        {
            logging("could not open the output file");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    
    if (avformat_write_header(encoder->avfc, NULL) < 0)
    {
        logging("an error occurred when opening output file");
        return -1;
    }

    AVFrame *input_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    AVPacket *input_packet = av_packet_alloc();
   
    int key = 0;

    //Ends the loop when Esc key is pressed.
    while (key != 27)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            key = _getch();
        }

        int ret = av_read_frame(decoder->avfc, input_packet);
        if(ret<0)
            break;
        if (decoder->avfc->streams[input_packet->stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            if (transcode_video(decoder, encoder, input_packet, input_frame))
                return -1;
            av_packet_unref(input_packet);

        }
        else if (decoder->avfc->streams[input_packet->stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            if (remux(&input_packet, &encoder->avfc, decoder->audio_avs->time_base, encoder->audio_avs->time_base, &audio_tt))
                return -1;

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            av_packet_unref(input_packet);
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
        else
        {
            logging("Ignoring all nonvideo or audio packets.");
        }
    }

    if (encode_video(decoder, encoder, NULL))
        return -1;
    

    av_write_trailer(encoder->avfc);


    if (input_frame != NULL)
    {
        av_frame_free(&input_frame);
        input_frame = NULL;
    }

    if (input_packet != NULL)
    {
        av_packet_free(&input_packet);
        input_packet = NULL;
    }

    avformat_close_input(&decoder->avfc);

    avformat_free_context(decoder->avfc);
    decoder->avfc = NULL;
    avformat_free_context(encoder->avfc);
    encoder->avfc = NULL;

    avcodec_free_context(&decoder->video_avcc);
    decoder->video_avcc = NULL;
    avcodec_free_context(&decoder->audio_avcc);
    decoder->audio_avcc = NULL;

    free(decoder);
    decoder = NULL;
    free(encoder);
    encoder = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Now both the audio and the video looks and sounds OK.

Comment: Will it work if the output is also an rtsp stream? I am just throwing out the ideas because that's my endgoal. Because for now, the code you gave is not working for me even for `libx264`.

Comment: Nevermind audio is working fine for longer video files. But no video is being written to output file.

Comment: In order for the video to partially work, you have to close the output file gracefully. Stop the RTSP transmission (to `rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream` ) so that the code reachs `av_write_trailer(encoder->avfc);`, and then ends with `return 0;`.

Comment: I updated the answer. When streaming in a loop, add `setpts` and `asetpts` filters. For finishing execution with valid MP4 file, press `Esc` (the updated code waits for `Esc` key press instead of using an endless loop with `while(1)`). The MP4 file looks and sounds OK.

Comment: Thanks. Video is not very good, but at least it is working somewhat.

Comment: For improving the video quality try: `ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v];[0:a]asetpts=N/SR/TB[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -ac 2 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream`

Comment: It is close enough, I guess. I am accepting your answer.

Comment: A bug I noticed, the code works when the number of frames is less than around 2000. After that, the same error pops and the output file is not written(due to memory leak?). Basically, the code is only delaying the error, not eliminating it. Can you please add this in the answer so that people can know this, along with the fact that video output is still glitched?

Comment: As far as I can see, this time the issue is related the video stream. There are too many issues that I don't know how to fix... Once of the issues is that the CPU is too busy. The `ffmpeg -re -stream_loop...` command encodes H.264 video at 60fps. For testing, we may reduce the realtime rate to 6Hz: `ffmpeg -readrate 0.1 -stream_loop -1 -i small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v];[0:a]asetpts=N/SR/TB[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -ac 2 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream`

Comment: Getting the error `pts (1024) < dts (1574122160956548149) in stream 0`. So, no It doesn't work. Is it occurring because of too many frames queuing up in the encoder. If yes, maybe we can skip some frames and only pick the latest frame. I don't know, but is it possible?

Comment: Yes, when re-encoding, we can skip as much frames as we like. Note that we have to decode all the video packets, but may skip frames (reducing the frame rate) when encoding. In my machine `-readrate 0.1` seems to work (but there are other issues). The CPU is too loaded because the command line encodes H.264 1920x1080 at 60fps. The C code encodes only 854x480 at 60Hz - with H.264 codec it's OK (AV1 encoding is probably too much). What CPU model are you using?

Comment: I was running the program on ubuntu running on wsl. So, no doubt it was slow.