# "Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 47104 >= -4251" in C ffmpeg video & audio streams processing

Tags: c, ffmpeg

For an input.mp4 file containing a video stream and an audio stream, intend to convert the video stream into h264 codec and the audio stream into aac codec and combine the two streams in output.mp4 file using C and ffmpeg libraries.
Am getting an error [mp4 @ 0x5583c88fd340] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 47104 >= -4251
How do i solve that error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>    
#include <libavutil/opt.h>

int encodeVideoAndAudio4(char *pInName, char *pOutName) {

    AVFormatContext *format_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();

    AVCodecContext *video_dec_ctx = NULL;
    AVCodecContext *video_enc_ctx = NULL;
    AVCodec *video_dec_codec = NULL;
    AVCodec *video_enc_codec = NULL;
    AVDictionary *video_enc_opts = NULL;

    AVCodecContext *audio_dec_ctx = NULL;
    AVCodecContext *audio_enc_ctx = NULL;
    AVCodec *audio_dec_codec = NULL;
    AVCodec *audio_enc_codec = NULL;


    if (avformat_open_input(&format_ctx, pInName, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open input file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(format_ctx, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not find stream information\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < format_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        AVStream *stream = format_ctx->streams[i];
        const char *media_type_str = av_get_media_type_string(stream->codecpar->codec_type);
        AVRational time_base = stream->time_base;

    }

    int video_stream_index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < format_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (format_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            video_stream_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (video_stream_index == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not find a video stream\n");
        return 1;
    }

    AVStream *videoStream = format_ctx->streams[video_stream_index];
    video_dec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(NULL);
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(video_dec_ctx, videoStream->codecpar);

    video_dec_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(video_dec_ctx->codec_id);

    if (!video_dec_codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported video codec!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (avcodec_open2(video_dec_ctx, video_dec_codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open a video decoder codec\n");
        return 1;
    }

    video_enc_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!video_enc_codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Video Encoder codec not found\n");
        return 1;
    }

    video_enc_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(video_enc_codec);
    if (!video_enc_ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate video encoder codec context\n");
        return 1;
    }

    videoStream->time_base = (AVRational){1, 25};

    video_enc_ctx->bit_rate = 1000; 
    video_enc_ctx->width = video_dec_ctx->width;
    video_enc_ctx->height = video_dec_ctx->height;
    video_enc_ctx->time_base = (AVRational){1, 25};
    video_enc_ctx->gop_size = 10;
    video_enc_ctx->max_b_frames = 1;
    video_enc_ctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    if (avcodec_open2(video_enc_ctx, video_enc_codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open encoder codec\n");
        return 1;
    }

    av_dict_set(&video_enc_opts, "preset", "medium", 0);
    av_opt_set_dict(video_enc_ctx->priv_data, &video_enc_opts);

    AVPacket video_pkt;
    av_init_packet(&video_pkt);
    video_pkt.data = NULL;
    video_pkt.size = 0;

    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;
    pkt.size = 0;

    AVFrame *video_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!video_frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate video frame\n");
        return 1;
    }

    video_frame->format = video_enc_ctx->pix_fmt;
    video_frame->width = video_enc_ctx->width;
    video_frame->height = video_enc_ctx->height;
   
    int audio_stream_index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < format_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (format_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            audio_stream_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (audio_stream_index == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not find an audio stream\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    AVStream *audioStream = format_ctx->streams[audio_stream_index];
    audio_dec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(NULL);
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(audio_dec_ctx, audioStream->codecpar);
    
    audio_dec_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(audio_dec_ctx->codec_id);
   
    if (!audio_dec_codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported audio codec!\n");
        return 1;
    }
   
    if (avcodec_open2(audio_dec_ctx, audio_dec_codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open Audio decoder codec\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    audio_enc_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
    if (!audio_enc_codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Audio Encoder codec not found\n");
        return 1;
    }
   
    audio_enc_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(audio_enc_codec);
    if (!audio_enc_ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate audio encoder codec context\n");
        return 1;
    }

    audioStream->time_base = (AVRational){1, audio_dec_ctx->sample_rate};
    
    audio_enc_ctx->bit_rate = 64000; 
    audio_enc_ctx->sample_rate = audio_dec_ctx->sample_rate;
    audio_enc_ctx->channels = audio_dec_ctx->channels;
    audio_enc_ctx->channel_layout = av_get_default_channel_layout(audio_enc_ctx->channels);
    audio_enc_ctx->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;
    audio_enc_ctx->profile = FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW;
    
    if (avcodec_open2(audio_enc_ctx, audio_enc_codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open encoder codec\n");
        return 1;
    }
   
    AVPacket audio_pkt;
    av_init_packet(&audio_pkt);
    audio_pkt.data = NULL;
    audio_pkt.size = 0;
   
    AVFrame *audio_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!audio_frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate audio frame\n");
        return 1;
    }

    audio_frame->format = audio_enc_ctx->sample_fmt;
    audio_frame->sample_rate = audio_enc_ctx->sample_rate;
    audio_frame->channels = audio_enc_ctx->channels;
   
    AVFormatContext *output_format_ctx = NULL;
    if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(&output_format_ctx, NULL, NULL, pOutName) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not create output context\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (avio_open(&output_format_ctx->pb, pOutName, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open output file\n");
        return 1;
    }
   
    AVStream *video_stream = avformat_new_stream(output_format_ctx, video_enc_codec);
    if (!video_stream) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not create video stream\n");
        return 1;
    }
   
    av_dict_set(&video_stream->metadata, "rotate", "90", 0);
    
    if (avcodec_parameters_from_context(video_stream->codecpar, video_enc_ctx) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not copy video codec parameters\n");
        return 1;
    }
  
    AVStream *audio_stream = avformat_new_stream(output_format_ctx, audio_enc_codec);
    if (!audio_stream) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not create audio stream\n");
        return 1;
    }
   
    if (avcodec_parameters_from_context(audio_stream->codecpar, audio_enc_ctx) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not copy audio codec parameters\n");
        return 1;
    }
  
    if (avformat_write_header(output_format_ctx, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not write header\n");
        return 1;
    }
  
     int video_frame_count = 0, audio_frame_count = 0;
    
    while (1) {

        if (av_read_frame(format_ctx, &pkt) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "BREAK FROM MAIN WHILE LOOP\n");
            break;
        }

        if (pkt.stream_index == video_stream_index) {

            if (avcodec_send_packet(video_dec_ctx, &pkt) < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not send video packet for decoding\n");
                return 1;
            }

            while (avcodec_receive_frame(video_dec_ctx, video_frame) == 0) { 

                if (avcodec_send_frame(video_enc_ctx, video_frame) < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not send video frame for encoding\n");
                    return 1;
                }

                while (avcodec_receive_packet(video_enc_ctx, &video_pkt) == 0) {
                    
                    if (av_write_frame(output_format_ctx, &video_pkt) < 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not write video packet to output file.\n");
                        return 1;
                    }

                    av_packet_unref(&video_pkt);
                }

                video_frame_count++;
            }
        } else if (pkt.stream_index == audio_stream_index) {

            if (avcodec_send_packet(audio_dec_ctx, &pkt) < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not send audio packet for decoding\n");
                return 1;
            }

            while (avcodec_receive_frame(audio_dec_ctx, audio_frame) == 0) { 
 
                if (avcodec_send_frame(audio_enc_ctx, audio_frame) < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not send audio frame for encoding\n");
                    return 1;
                }

                while (avcodec_receive_packet(audio_enc_ctx, &audio_pkt) == 0) {                    if (av_write_frame(output_format_ctx, &audio_pkt) < 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not write audio packet to output file\n");
                        return 1;
                    }

                    av_packet_unref(&audio_pkt);
                }

                audio_frame_count++;
            }
        }

        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }

    if (av_write_trailer(output_format_ctx) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not write trailer\n");
        return 1;
    }  
    
    avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
    avio_close(output_format_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(output_format_ctx);
    
    av_frame_free(&video_frame);
    avcodec_free_context(&video_dec_ctx);
    avcodec_free_context(&video_enc_ctx);
    av_dict_free(&video_enc_opts);
    
    av_frame_free(&audio_frame);
    avcodec_free_context(&audio_dec_ctx);
    avcodec_free_context(&audio_enc_ctx);

    printf("Conversion complete.  %d video frames processed and %d audio frames processed.\n",video_frame_count, audio_frame_count);

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <input.mp4> <output.mp4>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    const char *input_filename = argv[1];
    const char *output_filename = argv[2];

    avcodec_register_all();
    av_register_all();

    int returnValue = encodeVideoAndAudio4(input_filename, output_filename);
    
    return 0;
}
```

When i comment out the blocks that process one of the two streams, the other stream is converted and written to the output.mp4 successfully.
When each stream is processed in a separate loop, only the first stream is processed and written to the output.mp4 file and the other stream is skipped.
When both streams are processed in a common loop as it is in the code above, the above mentioned error appears.

Comment: possibly related or helpful: [ERROR "Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 1: 6874 >= 6874" while writing encoded output to an mp4 file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76197705)